# How can I add a column to an R set, containing the amount of matches of a regex

Tags: sql, r

To be able to execute regular expressions in SQL Server without the use of CLR, I'm looking into using R language. I have a set of texts, and I want to count the number of matches of a regex on each row.

**Note**: the "R" part can be found within the `@script` variable in the code block shown below. This is the part where this issue is.

For the sake of example: I have a table `InputData`:

```
CREATE TABLE InputData (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Text NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

This table contains 3 rows:

```
INSERT INTO InputData(Text)
VALUES ('This is the first row'),
       ('This is the second row'),
       ('This is the third row')
```

I'd like to run a query, that returns the number of time the letter `i` is found in each row, by using a regex (since the actual search I need is a bit more complicated). After some googling, I came up with the following:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTE_EXTERNAL_SCRIPT 
    @Language=N'R', 
    @script = N'pattern = ".*i.*"
    outData <- inData;
    outData$MatchCount <- length(gregexpr(pattern, outData$Text));'
, @input_data_1 = N'select ID, Text, 0 MatchCount from InputData'
, @input_data_1_name = N'inData'
, @output_data_1_name=N'outData'
with result sets ((ID INT, Text NVARCHAR(MAX), MatchCount INT));
```

Now the above doesn't work, because the `regexpr` runs the expression over the entire set, and will always return "3", since the set contains 3 rows. I would like it to return the number of matches per row, and put the result in the correct row.

So the result should be:

```
1, 'This is the first row', 3
2, 'This is the second row' 2
3, 'This is the third row', 3
```

Ideally, I wouldn't even need to return the text in the resulting set. Only the ID and match count is enough

Comment: What have you tried in R? Coz the above isn't R

Comment: @broti the part in the variable named "script" is R

Comment: Ah - missed that part.

Comment: I think your regex isn't correct if you want to count number of "i". Are you allowed to use non-base packages. Can you try `outData$MatchCount <- stringr::str_count(outData$Text, 'i')`

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not sure, I'll give it a go

Comment: @PaulVrugt Try `lengths(gregexpr(pattern="(i)+", outData$Text))`.

Comment: @jay.sd, that doesn work:
replacement has 0 rows, data has 10

Comment: @RonakShah apparently I can't, so using str_count is not an option

Comment: @PaulVrugt `o <- data.frame(t=c("i", "i i", "i i i"));lengths(gregexpr("(i+)+", o$t))` works for me though, where's the difference?

Comment: Ok..another attempt using base R : `outData$MatchCount <- sapply(gregexpr("i", outData$Text, fixed=TRUE), function(x) sum(x > 0))`